# Why does json.loads care which type of quotes are used?

Tags: python, json, string, python-2.7

In a python script I am parsing the return of
`gsettings get org.gnome.system.proxy ignore-hosts`
which looks like it should be properly formatted [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)
`['localhost', '127.0.0.0/8']`
however, when passing this output to [json.loads](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads) it throws
`ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded`

I make the call to gsettings via:

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(["gsettings", "get", "org.gnome.system.proxy", "ignore-hosts"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)  
stdout,stderr = proc.communicate()
```

which assigns `"['localhost', '127.0.0.0/8']\n"` to `stdout`.
Then I strip the newline and pass to json.loads:

```
ignore = json.loads(stdout.strip("\n"))
```

But, this throws a `ValueError`.

I've tracked the issue down to the string being defined by single-quotes or double-quotes as shown in the following snippet:

```
# tested in python 2.7.3

import json

ignore_hosts_works = '["localhost", "127.0.0.0/8"]'
ignore_hosts_fails = "['localhost', '127.0.0.0/8']"

json.loads(ignore_hosts_works) # produces list of unicode strings
json.loads(ignore_hosts_fails) # ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

import string
table = string.maketrans("\"'", "'\"")

json.loads(string.translate(ignore_hosts_fails, table)) # produces list of unicode strings
```

Why is `ignore_hosts_fails` not successfully parsed by `json.loads` without swapping the quote types?

In case it might matter, I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 with Python 2.7.3.

Comment: `['localhost', '127.0.0.0/8']` is not properly formatted JSON. JSON requires that **double** quotes are used. See [chapter 7 of the RFC](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7158#section-7), `quotation-mark` is defined as `"`.

Comment: Ah, thanks. The *double quotes* requirement did not stand out to me when reading http://www.json.org.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [JSON RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7158#section-7):

> ```
>   string = quotation-mark *char quotation-mark
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> ```
>   quotation-mark = %x22      ; "
> ```

JSON strings ***must*** use `"` quotes.

You can parse that list as a Python literal instead, using [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval("['localhost', '127.0.0.0/8']")
['localhost', '127.0.0.0/8']
```

Answer (score 0):

Because [RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159) says so.  Strings in JSON documents are enclosed in double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is *not* just JavaScript.

JSON strings are double quoted according to the spec [pdf](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf) or [json.org](http://json.org/).

JSON object keys are strings.

You **must** use double quotes for your strings and keys (to follow the spec). Many JSON parsers will be more permissive.

From `object` definition:

> An object structure is represented as a pair of curly bracket tokens surrounding zero or more name/value pairs.
>
> A name is a string. A single colon token follows each name, separating the name from the value. A single comma token separates a value from a following name.

From `string` definition:

> A string is a sequence of Unicode code points wrapped with quotation marks (U+0022).

That `U+0022` is the (double) quotation mark: `"`.

Answer (score 0):

As said before, that is invalid JSON. To parse, there are two other possibilities: use either `demjson` or `yaml`

```
>>> demjson.decode(" ['localhost', '127.0.0.0/8']")
[u'localhost', u'127.0.0.0/8']
>>> yaml.load(" ['localhost', '127.0.0.0/8']")
['localhost', '127.0.0.0/8']
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it cares for valid json. But you can tweak Simple json code to parse this Unquoted and single quoted json strings.

I have given my answer on this post

[Single versus double quotes in json loads in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14347047/single-versus-double-quotes-in-json-loads-in-python/48861504#48861504)