# Json formatting, python parsing

Tags: python, json, parsing

I have a json file that looks like this exactly:

```
{'data':[-99,19,1212,121,2131,323321,123]}
```

saved as `list.json`

and I have a python script that needs the list `[-99,19,1212,121,2131,323321,123]`

```
 import json

 with open ("list.json", "r") as myfile:
        data=myfile.read().replace('\n', '')
 spots1 = json.loads(data) #<-- Error
 spots = spots1['data']
```

Error:

```
File "pythonscript.py", line 479, in <module>
    spots1 = json.loads(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 326, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
```

I can't figure out what is wrong with my formatting.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: did you at the very least tried to print the content of `data` before parsing it?

Comment: You *don't have JSON*. JSON uses *double* quotes for strings.

Comment: Yes I did, and it doesn't seem to have a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python wants you to use "(double quote) for properties names in a json dictionary and not '(Single Quote)

Try this String:
{"data":[-99,19,1212,121,2131,323321,123]}

See this question for more details: [python: single vs double quotes in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162642/python-single-vs-double-quotes-in-json)