# Double quotes and single quotes in JSON String

Tags: json

I have a simple test JSON String:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JSON Object Creation in JavaScript</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var txt = '{"name":"Jimmy","street":"Hill Street","phone":"555 1234567"}';
//var txt = "{'name':'Jimmy','street':'Hill Street','phone':'555 1234567'}";

var obj = JSON.parse(txt);

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 
obj.name + "<br>" +
obj.street + "<br>" +
obj.phone;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Why the first one works and the second one not?

Any rules for JSON string with double quotes/single quotes?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can read about it on http://json.org/ and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types.2C_syntax_and_example . Same issue, different language: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4162642/218196

Comment: The official syntax allows only double quotes.  Some parsers will apparently accept single quotes, but that's non-standard.

Comment: Thanks. So when I generate JSON string from Java Code, it will be a troublesome to add so many \" in the string.

Comment: Better to create the appropriate Lists/Maps and use a JSON serializer.

Answer (score 1):

JSON requires double quotes for string literals.

See json.org.  For the JSON grammar in the context of JavaScript, see Sections 5.1.5 and 15.12.1 in the ECMAScipt Specification: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-5.1.5 .