# Python parsing JSON part of line in filePython

Tags: python, json

I would like to ask you for help with my json parsing. I've got file where every line looks like this one:

```
some hexadecimal numbers|something else|int|UA info|{'computer': {'os': {'version': 'blabla', 'name': 'blabla'}, 'app': {'version': 'blabla', 'name': 'blabla'}}}
```

I've got code which split every line into parts:

```
for line in some_file:
    line2 = line.split('|')
```

and I wanna to take the last part of each line (which should be in json format, at least i think so) and parse it for future use (I mean that I wanna write (to another file) os=name version, app=name version). I tried something like this:

```
json_string = json.loads(line2[4])
```

but python tells me some errors:

> Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

or

> No JSON object could be decoded

I know that it's something stupid, but i don't know what to do...
I would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an JSON, but looks like python literal.

You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to convert to python object:

```
import ast
ast.literal_eval(lines2[4])
```

BTW, there's one missing close bracket in the question, so:

```
ast.literal_eval(lines2[4] + '}')
```

Comment: And after that? How can I access the individual parts?

Answer (score 0):

*JSON [requires double quotes for strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162642/python-single-vs-double-quotes-in-json)*. Which means that you cannot load it as is with `json`.

I would use [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to parse the pipe-delimited file and [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to safely load the last column values into Python dictionaries:

```
import csv
from ast import literal_eval


with open("file.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter="|")
    data = [literal_eval(line[-1]) for line in reader]

print(data)  # data contains a list of dictionaries now
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON requires `double quotes` for any string literal.

> A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in double quotes, using backslash escapes. - http://www.json.org/

One **easy** and **safe** way to get it parsed is to use any [YAML parser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyYAML).
YAML can parse JSON and is less strict on the syntax.

```
>>> import yaml # from package pyyaml
>>> yaml.load("{'test': 'ok'}")
{'test': 'ok'}
>>> data = yaml.load("{'computer': {'os': {'version': 'blabla', 'name': 'blabla'}, 'app': {'version': 'blabla', 'name': 'blabla'}}}")
>>> data.get('computer').get('app').get('version')
'blabla'
```

And for the pipe delimited data, you can split them like you do, or use `csv` module to do it. Bonus, you can pass every chunk of data to `yaml.load` and it will handle the conversion:

```
import csv
import StringIO

some_file = StringIO.StringIO("0x1337|something else|12456789|UA info|{'computer': {'os': {'version': 'blabla', 'name': 'blabla'}, 'app': {'version': 'blabla', 'name': 'blabla'}}}")
elements = csv.reader(some_file, delimiter="|")
for element in elements[0]:
    print(yaml.load(element))
```

***Output***:

> 4919
>   something else
>   12456789
>   UA info
>   {'computer': {'app': {'version': 'blabla', 'name': 'blabla'}, 'os': {'version': 'blabla', 'name': 'blabla'}}}