# converting JSON to string in Python

Tags: python, json, string

I did not explain my questions clearly at beginning.
Try to use `str()` and `json.dumps()` when converting JSON to string in python.

```
>>> data = {'jsonKey': 'jsonValue',"title": "hello world"}
>>> print json.dumps(data)
{"jsonKey": "jsonValue", "title": "hello world"}
>>> print str(data)
{'jsonKey': 'jsonValue', 'title': 'hello world'}
>>> json.dumps(data)
'{"jsonKey": "jsonValue", "title": "hello world"}'
>>> str(data)
"{'jsonKey': 'jsonValue', 'title': 'hello world'}"
```

My question is:

```
>>> data = {'jsonKey': 'jsonValue',"title": "hello world'"}
>>> str(data)
'{\'jsonKey\': \'jsonValue\', \'title\': "hello world\'"}'
>>> json.dumps(data)
'{"jsonKey": "jsonValue", "title": "hello world\'"}'
>>>
```

My expected output: `"{'jsonKey': 'jsonValue','title': 'hello world''}"`

```
>>> data = {'jsonKey': 'jsonValue',"title": "hello world""}
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    data = {'jsonKey': 'jsonValue',"title": "hello world""}
                                                          ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
>>> data = {'jsonKey': 'jsonValue',"title": "hello world\""}
>>> json.dumps(data)
'{"jsonKey": "jsonValue", "title": "hello world\\""}'
>>> str(data)
'{\'jsonKey\': \'jsonValue\', \'title\': \'hello world"\'}'
```

My expected output: `"{'jsonKey': 'jsonValue','title': 'hello world\"'}"`

It is not necessary to change the output string to json (dict) again for me.

How to do this?

Comment: The second form is not JSON, essentially.

Comment: There is a big difference when you have single vs double quotes, try loading  with json.loads using the str version

Comment: `json.dumps()` is for converting **to** JSON, not from JSON to string.

Comment: `str` has _absolutely nothing_ to do with JSON; the fact that `str(somedict)` looks sort of like JSON is coincidence. `str` gets a string representation of an object, which may look nothing like JSON (ex. for classes that implement `__str__`).

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo I know, In fact, I am more interested in their difference in single quote and double quote in output strings when the input are jsons.

Comment: @BAE JSON requires double-quote strings. Single-quoted strings in JSON are invalid.

Answer (score 184, accepted):

[`json.dumps()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dumps) is much more than just making a string out of a Python object, it would always produce a *valid [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) string* (assuming everything inside the object is serializable) following the [Type Conversion Table](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#py-to-json-table).

For instance, if one of the values is `None`, the `str()` would produce an invalid JSON which cannot be loaded:

```
>>> data = {'jsonKey': None}
>>> str(data)
"{'jsonKey': None}"
>>> json.loads(str(data))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

But the `dumps()` would convert `None` into `null` making a valid JSON string that can be loaded:

```
>>> import json
>>> data = {'jsonKey': None}
>>> json.dumps(data)
'{"jsonKey": null}'
>>> json.loads(json.dumps(data))
{u'jsonKey': None}
```

Comment: In fact, I am more interested in their difference in single quote and double quote in the output string.

Comment: @BAE well, in this case it is simple: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162642/python-single-vs-double-quotes-in-json.

Answer (score 1):

There are other differences. For instance, `{'time': datetime.now()}` cannot be serialized to JSON, but can be converted to string. You should use one of these tools depending on the purpose (i.e. will the result later be decoded).

Comment: In fact, I am more interested in their difference in single quotes and double quotes.

Comment: Then alecxe has answered you.