# Working with string and json in python (json.loads json.dumps)

Tags: python, json

I have the following string:

```
 results = "{'eventid': '766', 'category': '0', 'uptime': '0', 'severity': '0', 'traptime': '0', 'formatline': '0', 'hostname': '0', 'community': '0', 'agentip': '192.168.250.50', 'eventname': '1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0', 'timestamp': '17-12-2015', 'trapoid': '0', 'enterprise': '0'}, {'eventid': '1.3.6.1.4.1.3955.2.7.1', 'category': '0', 'uptime': '0', 'severity': '0', 'traptime': '0', 'formatline': '0', 'hostname': '0', 'community': '0', 'agentip': '192.168.250.50', 'eventname': '1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.1.0', 'timestamp': '17-12-2015', 'trapoid': '0', 'enterprise': '0'}"
```

And I would like to parse it to JSON. My attempts:

```
results = json.loads(results)
```

Gives me a

> ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

Changing the string to:

```
results = "'details': {'eventid': '766', 'category': '0', 'uptime': '0', 'severity': '0', 'traptime': '0', 'formatline': '0', 'hostname': '0', 'community': '0', 'agentip': '192.168.250.50', 'eventname': '1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0', 'timestamp': '17-12-2015', 'trapoid': '0', 'enterprise': '0'}, {'eventid': '1.3.6.1.4.1.3955.2.7.1', 'category': '0', 'uptime': '0', 'severity': '0', 'traptime': '0', 'formatline': '0', 'hostname': '0', 'community': '0', 'agentip': '192.168.250.50', 'eventname': '1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.1.0', 'timestamp': '17-12-2015', 'trapoid': '0', 'enterprise': '0'}"
```

Gives me

> ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me. I had to change your single quotes to double quotes below, because like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4162651/3194712) stated, JSON syntax is not Python syntax. You also need to put your 2 JSON objects into an array of objects, and under the "details" key if you want it that way.

```
import json

results = "{'details':[{'eventid': '766', 'category': '0', 'uptime': '0', 'severity': '0', 'traptime': '0', 'formatline': '0', 'hostname': '0', 'community': '0', 'agentip': '192.168.250.50', 'eventname': '1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0', 'timestamp': '17-12-2015', 'trapoid': '0', 'enterprise': '0'}, {'eventid': '1.3.6.1.4.1.3955.2.7.1', 'category': '0', 'uptime': '0', 'severity': '0', 'traptime': '0', 'formatline': '0', 'hostname': '0', 'community': '0', 'agentip': '192.168.250.50', 'eventname': '1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.1.0', 'timestamp': '17-12-2015', 'trapoid': '0', 'enterprise': '0'}]}"

results = results.replace("'", '"')
data = json.loads(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

*This is not a valid JSON* since it has single quotes and not double quotes.

One option would be to *safely* eval this string with [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> results = "{'eventid': '766', 'category': '0', 'uptime': '0', 'severity': '0', 'traptime': '0', 'formatline': '0', 'hostname': '0', 'community': '0', 'agentip': '192.168.250.50', 'eventname': '1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0', 'timestamp': '17-12-2015', 'trapoid': '0', 'enterprise': '0'}, {'eventid': '1.3.6.1.4.1.3955.2.7.1', 'category': '0', 'uptime': '0', 'severity': '0', 'traptime': '0', 'formatline': '0', 'hostname': '0', 'community': '0', 'agentip': '192.168.250.50', 'eventname': '1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.1.0', 'timestamp': '17-12-2015', 'trapoid': '0', 'enterprise': '0'}"
>>> literal_eval(results)[0]['eventid']
'766'
```