# Read text file of dictionaries into python as list

Tags: python, dictionary, io

I have a big file of text that is a list of dictionaries, like so

```
[{'a':'1', 'b':'2'},{'a':'3','b':'4'}]
```

How do i read this into python as a list of dictionaries?

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `ast.literal_eval`.

```
import ast
ast.literal_eval("[{'a':'1', 'b':'2'},{'a':'3','b':'4'}]")
```

> Help on function literal_eval in module ast:
>
> literal_eval(node_or_string)
>       Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python
>       expression.  The string or node provided may only consist of the  following
>       Python literal structures: strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts,    sets, booleans, and None.

I learnt this trick at https://stackoverflow.com/a/21154138/1415639

Comment: ah, you beat me for 9 secs

Answer (score 2):

You can use [eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval):

```
with open('filename') as f:
    d = eval(f.read())
```

Bear in mind that `eval` should be used with care, as mentioned in the comments, because you may end up executing harmful code if the input is not 100% in your control.

Comment: `eval` can do bad things if you don't have 100% control over the file contents.

Comment: @MarkRansom Very true. Added a notice.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `literal_eval` from `ast` which is a safer solution of eval. 
You can see why you shouldn't use `eval` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933451/why-should-exec-and-eval-be-avoided).

So what you want would be:

```
from ast import literal_eval


with open('file.txt') as f:
    dictionaries = literal_eval(f.read().strip())
```