# How to read in a .txt file as a dictionary?

Tags: python, file, dictionary, text

I have a file `output.txt` who's contents are already in a python dictionary format:

```
output.txt = {'id':123, 'user': 'abc', 'date':'20-08-1998'}
```

When I read the file into python I get the following:

```
f = open('output.txt','r', encoding='utf8')
print(f)
>>> <_io.TextIOWrapper name='output.txt' mode='r' encoding='utf8'>
```

**How can I read the file in as a python dictionary?**

I have tried to use the `dict()` constructor, but I get this error:

```
f = dict(open('output.txt','r', encoding='utf8'))
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 15656; 2 is required
```

Comment: Use `ast.literal_eval()`. But really it would have been better to save this as JSON in the first place.

Comment: open returns a wrapper, not the contents of a file, so you cannot call directly dict to it. Instead you will need to read the lines to get the content

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `json` module:

```
with open('output.txt', 'r') as f:
    my_dict = json.loads(f.read())
```

However [JSON requires double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162642/single-vs-double-quotes-in-json), so this wouldn't work for your file. A work around would be to use `replace()`:

```
with open('output.txt', 'r') as f:
    my_dict = json.loads(f.read().replace("'", '"')

print(my_dict)
#{u'date': u'20-08-1998', u'id': 123, u'user': u'abc'}
```