# Ignore comma in quotes when using json.loads() / Python?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, sys

currently working with the below command:

```
python foo.py "['A,B,C,D','A,B,C','A,B','A']"
```

And I want to transform it into an actual string array:

```
A[0] = 'A,B,C,D'
A[1] = 'A,B,C' 
A[2] = 'A,B' 
A[3] = 'A'
```

At the moment, I've been trying to use `json.loads()` and `sys` to read the string into an object or list.

However, it seems that the presence of the single-quotes cause the following error.

```
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Yet, without the single-quotes, I end up the array:

```
B = ["A","B","C","D","A","B","C","A","B","A"]
```

How to get Python to ignore the inner commas while keeping track of the outer commas in order to produce the array of strings given in `A` shown above?

Comment: Your input isn't JSON, so...why use `json.loads`?

Comment: Why not use `'["A,B,C,D","A,B,C","A,B","A"]'`?

Comment: I can't find the duplicate right now, but your are looking for `ast.literal_eval`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I used it because it works on things like "[1,2,3,4]". This was the first time I've run into an issue like this one. Would you be able to recommend me another method to use?

Comment: @timgeb https://stackoverflow.com/a/21154138/2395133

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to...

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python
>       expression.  The string or node provided may only consist of the following
>       Python literal structures: strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts,
>       sets, booleans, and None.

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> literal_eval("['A,B,C,D','A,B,C','A,B','A']")
['A,B,C,D', 'A,B,C', 'A,B', 'A']
```