# Cannot read tweets from txt in Python 3

Tags: python, json, twitter

New to python. I scraped some tweets and store them in txt file. However, I can't open it with `json.loads` and it says

```
Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

The beginning of the file is something like

```
['{"created_at": ...]
```

in the txt file.

Really need some help! Thanks!

Comment: You are not writing JSON to the text file. Edit your question to describe how you stored the tweets and provide more sample that can be worked with.

Comment: It seems like the data with the txt file is not a [valid JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4162651/6699447). Use `ast.literal_eval` instead.