# How can I flatten a nested JSON with single quotes with Pandas?

Tags: python, json, pandas, nested, jupyter

I need to analyze metadata from here: http://jmcauley.ucsd.edu/data/amazon/links.html

However, metadata JSON files here are nested & have single quotes, not double quotes. Therefore I can't use json_normalize to flatten this data into a Pandas dataframe.

Example:

```
{'A':'1', 'B':{'c':['1','2'], 'd':['3','4']}}
```

I need to flatten this into a Pandas data frame with objects A B.c B.d
With guideline given in the link I used eval to get A and B but can't get B.c, B.d.

Could you please suggest a way to do this?

Comment: That's **not** JSON.

Answer (score 1):

A [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) cannot have keys or values encompassed in single quotes.
If you *have* to parse a string with single quotes as a dict then you can probably use

```
import ast
data = str({'A':'1', 'B':{'c':['1','2'], 'd':['3','4']}})
data_dict = ast.literal_eval(data)

from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
data_normalized = json_normalize(data)
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21154138/13561487

Answer (score 0):

That's a dict, not a JSON, if you want to convert that to a DataFrame, just do this:

```
d = {'A':'1', 'B':{'c':['1','2'], 'd':['3','4']}}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

   A       B
c  1  [1, 2]
d  1  [3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is loading this text into a python dict
you can try a couple of things

1. replace single quotes -> `json.loads(data.replace("'",'"'))`
2. try to read it as a python dict -> `eval(data)`