# Split nested JSON File into two JSONs according to their ID?

Tags: python, json, logic, filesplitting

I have nested JSON File which loaded as python dictionary called `movies_data` as follows:

```
with open('project_folder/data_movie_absa.json') as infile:
  movies_data = json.load(infile)
```

It has the following structure:

```
{ "review_1": {"tokens": ["Best", "show", "ever", "!"], 
               "movie_user_4": {"aspects": ["O", "B_A", "O", "O"], "sentiments": ["B_S", "O", "O", "O"]},  
               "movie_user_6": {"aspects": ["O", "B_A", "O", "O"], "sentiments": ["B_S", "O", "O", "O"]}}, 

  "review_2": {"tokens": ["Its", "a", "great", "show"], 
               "movie_user_1": {"aspects": ["O", "O", "O", "B_A"], "sentiments": ["O", "O", "B_S", "O"]}, 
               "movie_user_6": {"aspects": ["O", "O", "O", "B_A"], "sentiments": ["O", "O", "B_S", "O"]}},

  "review_3": {"tokens": ["I", "love", "this", "actor", "!"],  
               "movie_user_17": {"aspects": ["O", "O", "O", "B_A", "O"], "sentiments": ["O", "B_S", "O", "O", "O"]}, 
               "movie_user_23": {"aspects": ["O", "O", "O", "B_A", "O"], "sentiments": ["O", "B_S", "O", "O", "O"]}},

  "review_4": {"tokens": ["Bad", "movie"], 
               "movie_user_1": {"aspects": ["O", "B_A"], "sentiments": ["B_S", "O"]}, 
               "movie_user_6": {"aspects": ["O", "B_A"], "sentiments": ["B_S", "O"]}}

...
}
```

It has 3324 key-value pairs (i.e., up to key review_3224). I want to split this file into two json files (`train_movies.json`, `test_movies.json`) based on specific list of keys:

```
test_IDS = ['review_2', 'review_4']

with open("train_movies.json", "w", encoding="utf-8-sig") as outfile_train, open("test_movies.json", "w", encoding="utf-8-sig") as outfile_test:
  for review_id, review in movies_data.items():
    if review_id in test_IDS:
      outfile = outfile_test
      outfile.write('{"%s": "%s"}' % (review_id, movies_data[review_id]))
      
    else:
      outfile = outfile_train
      outfile.write('{"%s": "%s"}' % (review_id, movies_data[review_id]))
  outfile.close()
```

for test_movies.json I have the following structure:

```
{"review_2": "{'tokens': ['Its', 'a', 'great', 'show'], 
            'movie_user_4': {'aspects': ['O', 'O', 'O', 'B_A'], 'sentiments': ['O', 'O', 'B_S', 'O']}, 
            'movie_user_6': {'aspects': ['O', 'O', 'O', 'B_A'], 'sentiments': ['O', 'O', 'B_S', 'O']}}"}

{"review_4": "{'tokens': ['Bad', 'movie'], 
               'movie_user_1': {'aspects': ['O', 'B_A'], 'sentiments': ['B_S', 'O']},
               'movie_user_6': {'aspects': ['O', 'B_A'], 'sentiments': ['B_S', 'O']}}"}
```

Unfortunately, this structure has some **problems** like inconsistent double **quotes** (`" vs. '`), **no commas** between reviews etc... Therefore, I have the following problem by reading `test_movies.json` as `json` file:

```
with open('project_folder/test_movies.json') as infile:
  testing_data = json.load(infile)
```

The error message:

```
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-3548a718f421> in <module>()
      1 with open('/content/gdrive/My Drive/project_folder/test_movies.json') as infile:
----> 2   testing_data = json.load(infile)

1 frames
/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    342         if s.startswith('\ufeff'):
    343             raise JSONDecodeError("Unexpected UTF-8 BOM (decode using utf-8-sig)",
--> 344                                   s, 0)
    345     else:
    346         if not isinstance(s, (bytes, bytearray)):

JSONDecodeError: Unexpected UTF-8 BOM (decode using utf-8-sig): line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

The **desired output** should have a correct json structure like the original `movies_data` so python could read it correctly as a dict.

Could you help me please to correct my python code?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The problem you seem to be having is not related to the splitting, but the parsing of the single-quoted nested JSON. Please fix the title accordingly

Comment: If I had to guess, I would say the file is not a JSON but a list of JSONS, and the values for each `"review_i"` are python dictionaries plainly printed. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21154138/6843675) out to see how you can parse them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue**

- Need to use json.dumps to create the outut string to write to file.
- Using Python string formatting i.e. '{"%s": "%s"}' % (review_id, movies_data[review_id]) creates problems you described

**Code**

```
train, test = {}, {}   # Dicionaries for storing training and test data
for review_id, review in movies_data.items():
    if review_id in test_IDS:
        test[review_id] = review
    else:
        train[review_id] = review

# Output Test
with open("test_movies.json", "w") as outfile_test:
    json.dump(test, outfile_test)
    
# Output training
with open("train_movies.json", "w") as outfile_train:
    json.dump(train, outfile_train)
```

**Results**

*Input:* File Contents of test.json

```
{ "review_1": {"tokens": ["Best", "show", "ever", "!"], 
               "movie_user_4": {"aspects": ["O", "B_A", "O", "O"], "sentiments": ["B_S", "O", "O", "O"]},  
               "movie_user_6": {"aspects": ["O", "B_A", "O", "O"], "sentiments": ["B_S", "O", "O", "O"]}}, 

  "review_2": {"tokens": ["Its", "a", "great", "show"], 
               "movie_user_1": {"aspects": ["O", "O", "O", "B_A"], "sentiments": ["O", "O", "B_S", "O"]}, 
               "movie_user_6": {"aspects": ["O", "O", "O", "B_A"], "sentiments": ["O", "O", "B_S", "O"]}},

  "review_3": {"tokens": ["I", "love", "this", "actor", "!"],  
               "movie_user_17": {"aspects": ["O", "O", "O", "B_A", "O"], "sentiments": ["O", "B_S", "O", "O", "O"]}, 
               "movie_user_23": {"aspects": ["O", "O", "O", "B_A", "O"], "sentiments": ["O", "B_S", "O", "O", "O"]}},

  "review_4": {"tokens": ["Bad", "movie"], 
               "movie_user_1": {"aspects": ["O", "B_A"], "sentiments": ["B_S", "O"]}, 
               "movie_user_6": {"aspects": ["O", "B_A"], "sentiments": ["B_S", "O"]}}

}
```

*Output:* File Contents of test_movies.json

```
{"review_2": {"tokens": ["Its", "a", "great", "show"], "movie_user_1": {"aspects": ["O", "O", "O", "B_A"], "sentiments": ["O", "O", "B_S", "O"]}, "movie_user_6": {"aspects": ["O", "O", "O", "B_A"], "sentiments": ["O", "O", "B_S", "O"]}}, "review_4": {"tokens": ["Bad", "movie"], "movie_user_1": {"aspects": ["O", "B_A"], "sentiments": ["B_S", "O"]}, "movie_user_6": {"aspects": ["O", "B_A"], "sentiments": ["B_S", "O"]}}}
```

*Output:* File Contents of train_movies.json

```
{"review_1": {"tokens": ["Best", "show", "ever", "!"], "movie_user_4": {"aspects": ["O", "B_A", "O", "O"], "sentiments": ["B_S", "O", "O", "O"]}, "movie_user_6": {"aspects": ["O", "B_A", "O", "O"], "sentiments": ["B_S", "O", "O", "O"]}}, "review_3": {"tokens": ["I", "love", "this", "actor", "!"], "movie_user_17": {"aspects": ["O", "O", "O", "B_A", "O"], "sentiments": ["O", "B_S", "O", "O", "O"]}, "movie_user_23": {"aspects": ["O", "O", "O", "B_A", "O"], "sentiments": ["O", "B_S", "O", "O", "O"]}}}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still have two problems:
1- Each key-value pair (i.e., review) will get an extra curly bracket { }
2- There are no commas between each key-value pair. 
so the output cannot be read as json file :(

Comment: @AliF--easy enough to correct.  Error due to misunderstanding your desired output format.

Comment: to fix comma problem I've added in `outfile.write(result + ",\n")` still thinking about curly brace

Comment: @AliF--how is the output now?

Comment: @AliF--if the format is okay, as an improvement, we could make test_ids a random subset of all the keys in the original data.  This would be in keeping with how training and test data is normally based upon a random partitioning of the dataset.

Comment: the new jsons' files format seems as same as the original but still cannot be read as json file `with open('/content/gdrive/My Drive/project_folder/test_movies.json') as infile:
  testing_data = json.load(infile)` has the error `JSONDecodeError: Unexpected UTF-8 BOM (decode using utf-8-sig): line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Comment: @AliF--I'll take a look.

Comment: @AliF--the json files can now be read after I change the open for write to the usual `open("test_movies.json", "w")`.  Specifying encoding="utf-8-sig" caused the problem.