# nlohmann::detail::parse_error: syntax error while parsing CBOR string: expected length specification (0x60-0x7B) or indefinite string type (0x7F)

Tags: c++, cbor

Trying to use [nlohmann/json](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) to parse some CBOR payload:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>

using json = nlohmann::json;

int main()
{
    uint8_t data[] = {0xa2, 0x43, 0x72, 0x65, 0x74, 0x81, 0x0d, 0x47,
                      0x73, 0x75, 0x63, 0x63, 0x65, 0x73, 0x73, 0xf5};

    json jresp = json::from_cbor(data, data + (sizeof data / sizeof data[0]));

    return 0;
}
```

Fails with this error:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type nlohmann::detail::parse_error: [json.exception.parse_error.113] parse error at byte 2: syntax error while parsing CBOR string: expected length specification (0x60-0x7B) or indefinite string type (0x7F); last byte: 0x43

I tried other decoders, and those are able to decode that payload.

Python's [cbor](https://pypi.org/project/cbor/) package is able to decode it:

```
import cbor
print(cbor.loads(b"\xa2\x43\x72\x65\x74\x81\x0d\x47\x73\x75\x63\x63\x65\x73\x73\xf5"))
```

> {b'ret': [13], b'success': True}

CBOR playground at [cbor.me](http://cbor.me) is able to decode it:

16 bytes:

```
A2                   # map(2)
   43                # bytes(3)
      726574         # "ret"
   81                # array(1)
      0D             # unsigned(13)
   47                # bytes(7)
      73756363657373 # "success"
   F5                # primitive(21)
```

Diagnostic:

```
{'ret': [13], 'success': true}
```

Is there some flag to pass to [nlohmann/json](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) to make it decode it?

Tried to pass `strict=false` in `json::from_cbor()` to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with CBOR but it doesn't seem to prevent you from using binary strings, integers, etc. as JSON keys.

In your case the input data uses `0x43` to define a 3-byte binary key, instead of the expected `0x63` for a 3-byte string.
Something similar for `success`.

Using `{0xa2, 0x63, 0x72, 0x65, 0x74, 0x81, 0x0d, 0x67, 0x73, 0x75, 0x63, 0x63, 0x65, 0x73, 0x73, 0xf5};` works fine with nlohmann/json.

cbor.me differentiate between binary strings (single quotes) and text strings (double quotes).
JSON expects/requires double quotes for strings and JSON keys are defined as strings: https://www.json.org/json-en.html

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4162651/4181011

---

**Edit:**

What you have:

| JSON | CBOR |
| --- | --- |
| `{'ret': [13], 'success': true}` | `A2 # map(2)` `43 # bytes(3)` `726574 # "ret"` `81 # array(1)` `0D # unsigned(13)` `47 # bytes(7)` `73756363657373 # "success"` `F5 # primitive(21)` |

What you want/need:

| JSON | CBOR |
| --- | --- |
| `{"ret": [13], "success": true}` | `A2 # map(2)` `63 # text(3)` `726574 # "ret"` `81 # array(1)` `0D # unsigned(13)` `67 # text(7)` `73756363657373 # "success"` `F5 # primitive(21)` |

---

**Edit 2:**

You JSON is not valid. The error message says so.
At byte 2 the parser expects a string which in CBOR is introduced by the string length `(0x60-0x7B) or indefinite string type (0x7F)`.

Your CBOR payload does not introduce a string but bytes. That's why it is rejected by the parser. `0x43` is not a valid type/length identifier for strings and JSON requires a string at this point.

Comment: My payload comes from lua, where there is no notion of strings: everything is bytes, therefore keys (as well as string values) are bytes.

Comment: @fferri And lua is directly sending CBOR? Do you have access to the lua code? Can you change the notion from `'res'` to `"res"`? I would assume a lua json library to generate valid json and thereby correct CBOR.

Comment: @fferri Your JSON (whether encoded by CBOR or not) is not valid JSON. That's the problem.

Comment: Not possible with the codec I'm currently using (https://code.zash.se/lua-cbor/file/tip/cbor.lua), but there is another codec (https://github.com/spc476/CBOR) that encodes strings as CBOR TEXT wherever possible (says: "if a Lua string is valid UTF8, then it's encoded as a CBOR TEXT").