# why JSON.parse does not convert a string to json object?

Tags: javascript

I tried to convert a string to a javascript object using `JSON.parse` but it's not working.

I tried everything but did not get anything on the `console.log` and there is no error message.

```
JSON.parse(`{'exp': '1', 'input': '1d6404f66ed3d72e', 'iterate': 'no'}`);
```

**Update**

In the real code, I'm passing the value from an object

```
console.log(JSON.parse(future.onIOPub.data['text/plain']))
```

Comment: JSON requires double quotes.

Comment: Because your input isn't valid JSON. I'm pretty sure there _is_ an error message (I'd expect `Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1`), maybe you are swallowing exceptions somewhere with an empty `catch`?

Comment: I would say it's a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162642/single-vs-double-quotes-in-json/34855065 but people may be nit-picking about the `python` tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run this, you should see

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1
```

This error is because you are using single quotes. JSON only accepts double quotes, as described in the spec

https://www.json.org/json-en.html

Comment: In my real code, I'm not providing quotes manually rather I'm passing value from a variable, I Updated the code.

Comment: can you `console.log(["my-data", future.onIOPub.data['text/plain']])` and print here exactly what it prints?

Comment: It worked I just sliced off the single quote and it. worked.